# Leaflet/Mapbox Lat Lng Located Within Circle

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Anyone know if mapbox or leaflet can detect whether a point is located within an L.Circle? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try this? All the distances are in Meters.

```js
var radius = circle.getRadius(); //in meters
var circleCenterPoint = circle.getLatLng(); //gets the circle's center latlng
var isInCircleRadius = abs(circleCenterPoint.distanceTo(pointToTest)) <= radius;
```

Explanation:

You have some point. You have the circle's center point. You can just measure the distance between the point and circle, take the absolute value between the two and if it's less than the circle's radius, then it should be within the circle.

Right?

Comment: Yep!  That explanation is correct and works. I would just replace abs() with Math.abs()